# How to read Data field of Ethereum transaction

Tags: ethereum, web3py, ganache

I'm trying to post a transaction with a message on a local ethereum blockchain using the data field.
I don't know how to retrieve the message.

code:

```
import web3
w3 = web3.Web3(web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"))
alice = w3.eth.accounts[0]
text = b'Hello'
print(text)
tx = {
    'from': alice,
    'to': alice,
    'data': text,
}
tx_hash = w3.eth.sendTransaction(tx)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
my_tx = w3.eth.getTransaction(tx_hash)
print(my_tx.input)
```

output:

b'Hello'

0x48656c6c6f

I want to retrieve the original message 'Hello'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the transaction hash where the message was posted.

Then you can call `web3.eth.getTransaction(hash)` and you can read data back in `input` field.